# How to Free Variables Using Gekko

Tags: python-3.x, algebra, gekko

I am trying to use GEKKO to do simple algebra.

Given the Equation 6 = X1 * X2, I first set X1 to 2 using the Gekko `fix()` function. After solving and printing that equation, I try freeing X1 using the Gekko `free()` function and fix X2 to 2 using the `fix()` function again. The `free` function doesn't seem to be properly freeing the X2 Variable.

```
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

# Variables
x1 = m.Var()
x2 = m.Var()

# Equation
FindX1 = 6 == x1*x2
m.Equation(FindX1)

# Fix x1 to 2
m.fix(x1, val=2)

# Solve X2
m.solve(disp=False)
print("X1: %s and X2: %s" % (x1.VALUE, x2.VALUE))

# Fix x2 to 2
m.fix(x2, val=2)

# Free x1
m.free(x1)

# Solve X1
m.solve(disp=False)
print("X1: %s and X2: %s" % (x1.VALUE, x2.VALUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [restart file](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Files) is holding onto the specs. For `IMODE=3` it is `rto.t0` in the run directory `m.path`. You can remove that restart file with:

```py
import os
os.remove(m.path+'\\rto.t0')
```

There is an option `m.options.SPECS=0` that should also work to ignore the fixed / free specifications in the restart file but this isn't communicating to the solve engine. I created a [new GitHub issue to address this bug](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/97).

```py
import os
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Variables
x1 = m.Var()
x2 = m.Var()

# Equation
FindX1 = 6 == x1*x2
m.Equation(FindX1)

# Fix x1 to 2
m.fix(x1, val=2)

# Solve X2
m.solve(disp=False)
print("X1: %s and X2: %s" % (x1.VALUE, x2.VALUE))

# Fix x2 to 2
m.fix(x2, val=2)

# Free x1
m.free(x1)

os.remove(m.path+'\\rto.t0')
#m.options.SPECS = 0

# Solve X1
m.solve(disp=False)
print("X1: %s and X2: %s" % (x1.VALUE, x2.VALUE))

m.open_folder()
```

This produces the correct response:

```
X1: [2.0] and X2: [3.0]
X1: [3.0] and X2: [2.0]
```